# Show that the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{k_1} \theta \sin^{k_2} \theta d\theta = 0$ unless $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both even

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I did the cases where:

1. $\sin$, $\cos$ even
2. $\sin$ even, $\cos$ odd,
3. $\sin$ or $\cos$ odd

by using u-substitutions to rewrite the integrals as $\int_{a}^{a} f(x) \,dx = 0$.

How do I handle the even case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the substitution $u = \theta - \pi$ so that your integral becomes $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (-\cos 
 u)^{k_1}(-\sin u)^{k_2}\, \mathrm{d}u$$

If $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both even, then this is an (even/odd?) function in an even domain, so...?

Comment: It's an even function in an even domain therefore it has to be non-zero. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question is exactly as in your title, then you do not need to handle the even/even case.

"Unless"  means "if not".  So the question is

> if $k_1,k_2$ are not both even, then. . .

and the case where they **are** both even is not being asked.

(If you are asking the even/even case out of interest, I will leave it for someone else to answer.)